# Como criar um objeto e metodos em PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
class Database {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

e posso fazer isso:

```
require_once 'Database.php';
$db = new Database();
$db->usuarios();
```

Eu gostaria de poder fazer isso:

```
$db->usuarios->inserir($obj);
```

Isso é possível usando o método mágico `__call()`?

Comment: Vc quer dizer criar/adicionar métodos dinamicamente?

Comment: @rray, isto mesmo...

Comment: o seu método retorna algum valor? se sim, você pode mandar ele retornar o objeto de usuários e chamar o método insert.

Comment: O nome disso é fluent interface. Mas normalmente não usa-se o método mágico __call() a menos que queira transformar uma classe "não fluent" numa "estrutura fluent".

Comment: @BrumazziD.B., consegui fazer agora... porém fica assim $db->usuarios()->Insert(); tem como fazer sem precisa dos () no usuarios() ?

Comment: sendo um método creio que não, mas o se o seu "usuarios" fosse uma variável, é possível.

Comment: @BrumazziD.B. Show.. consegui usando o __get() ao invés de __call(). Obrigado, seus comentários me ajudaram a destravar o pensamento.

Comment: php não é meu forte, mas precisando é só chamar.

Comment: `usuarios->` teria que ser uma variavel da classe, não é melhor `usuarios()->` ? Eu raramente (nunca) vi ninguém fazendo isto `$foo->x->z()`, mas isto já é bem comum: `$foo->x()->z()`, existe alguma necessidade pra querer fazer da maneira que escreveu?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o NotORM usa neste estilo. Não tenho nenhuma necessidade especifica, apenas queria saber como poderia ser feito.

Comment: @MeuChapeu possivel é sim, na verdade é até fácil, seria usando `__get` e `__set`, mas é trabalhoso e o pior que ela pode ser "sobrescrita" (a não ser que faça uma validação no `__set`) vou tentar formular um exemplo. O método call só vai funcionar pra funções.

Comment: @MeuChapeu postei um exemplo, espero que ajude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No PHP o [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) é usado quando chamamos um método ou função, algo como `$baz->foo();`, ao chamar `$baz->y->x();` o `__call` não é disparado, pois o `->y` é uma variável do objeto, pra isto você deve ler sobre [`__get`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) e [`__set`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set), eles são disparados quando tentamos gravar ou ler dados/variáveis inacessíveis (não declarados na classe).

Segue um exemplo:

```
<?php
//Classe da tabela usuarios
class ClasseUsuarios
{
    public function inserir($b)
    {
    }
}

//Classe principal
class Database
{
    private $forceWrite = false;
    private $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
            //Libera a gravação de qualquer dado em $this->data
            $this->forceWrite = true;

            //Define a classe ClasseUsuarios para $this->data[usuario]
            $this->usuarios = new ClasseUsuarios();

            //Bloqueia a gravação da variável $this->data[usuario]
            $this->forceWrite = false;
    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        //Checa se é permitido o valor $this->data[usuarios]
        if ($key !== 'usuarios' || $this->forceWrite) {
            //Grava o valor para variáveis não declaradas na classe
            $this->data[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        //Lê o valor de variáveis não declaradas na classe
        return isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : NULL;
    }

    public function __isset($key)
    {
        //Se usar empty ou isset em variáveis não declaras irá verificar se ela existe em `$this->data`
        return isset($this->data[$key]);
    }
}

//Objeto ficticio
$obj = array();

//Chama a classe principal
$foo = new Database();

//Vai chamar o método new ClasseUsuarios()->inserir();
$foo->usuarios->inserir($obj);

$foo->usuarios = NULL; //Se tentar gravar a variavel usuarios nada acontece

/*
 * Vai chamar o método new ClasseUsuarios()->inserir();
 * sem ser afetado pelo `$foo->usuarios = NULL;`
 */
$foo->usuarios->inserir($obj);
```

Documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Answer (score 1):

Em **PHP** isso se chama **lambda_style** ou **Função Anônima**, para deixar mais a fácil a implementação crie uma **Classe Auxiliar** (DinamicMethod), agora é só se divertir :) e testar.

Não tente direto na classe **Database**, o método **__call**, não foi projetado para buscar **Função Anônima** dentro de atributos e sim de classe, por isso fizemos a classe **DinamicMethod**.

```
<?php

class DinamicMethod {

    public function __construct() {

        #leia sobre create_function http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.create-function.php
        $this->inserir = create_function('', 'echo "Eu sou Uma funcao anonima";');
        $this->deletar = create_function('', 'echo "Eu sou Uma funcao anonima e deleto";');

    }


    public function __call($metodo, $argumentos) {

        #Checa se o objeto ou a classe tem uma propriedade
        if (property_exists($this, $metodo)) {

            #Verifica se o conteúdo da variável pode ser chamado como função
            if (is_callable($this->$metodo)) {
                #Chama uma dada função de usuário com um array de parâmetros
                return call_user_func_array($this->$metodo, $argumentos);
            }
        }
    }
}


class Database {

    public $usuario;

    public function __construct() {

        #objeto de classe padrão php
        $this->usuario = new DinamicMethod();       

    }




}

$db = new Database();
$db->usuario->deletar();
```